# vertex coordinates in panel made with python script do not update

Tags: python, mesh

I modified the UI panel simple template so that the coordinates of the vertices of the selected object will be listed:

```
class HelloWorldPanel(bpy.types.Panel):
    """Creates a Panel in the Object properties window"""
    bl_label = "Hello World Panel"
    bl_idname = "OBJECT_PT_hello"
    bl_space_type = 'PROPERTIES'
    bl_region_type = 'WINDOW'
    bl_context = "object"

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout

        obj = context.object

        row = layout.row()
        row.label(text="Hello world!", icon='WORLD_DATA')

        row = layout.row()
        row.label(text="Active object is: " + obj.name)
        row = layout.row()
        row.prop(obj, "name")

        row = layout.row()
        row.operator("mesh.primitive_cube_add")
        
        vNum = len(obj.data.vertices)
        for i in range(vNum):
            v = obj.data.vertices[i].co
            layout.label("vertex " + str(i) + ": (%f %f %f)" % (v[0],v[1],v[2]))
```

This does print vertex coordinates in the panel:

[image]

However, the coordinates remain unchanged when I move the plane. How can I make the vertex coordinates update real-time?

Comment: When I run this here, the values are updated on leaving edit mode (you have to move the vertices in edit mode because you read the raw mesh coordinates without object transformations).

Comment: @B.Y.O.B. Ok, that worked. I didn't realize that moving the object around as a whole shouldn't change vertex positions.